# Loop Post Types with Name and Links

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I'm trying to create a menu which loops through the registered custom post types and links to their archive pages.  I've been able to get the list of post type names but it is not generating the links.  It only outputs a en empty anchor tag wrapped around the post types name.

```
$args = array( 'public' => true,'_builtin' => false );
$output = 'names';
$operator = 'and';
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
    $link = get_post_type_archive_link($post_type);
    echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $post_type . '</a></li>';
}
```

This is my output.

```
<li><a href="">posttypeA</a></li>
<li><a href="">posttypeB</a></li>
<li><a href="">posttypeC</a></li>
```

I have archive-posttypeX.php files for each post type.

[image]

All of my custom post types are registered similarly to this one:

```
function post_type_snippets() {
    register_post_type('snippets', array(
        'label'=>'Snippets',
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'labels'=>array(
            'name'=>_x('Snippets', 'post type general name'),
            'singular_name'=>_x('Snippet', 'post type singular name'),
            'add_new'=>_x('Add New', 'snippets'),
            'add_new_item'=>__('Add New Snippet'),
            'edit_item'=>__('Edit Snippet'),
            'new_item'=>__('New Snippet'),
            'view_item'=>__('View Snippet'),
            'search_items'=>__('Search Snippets'),
            'not_found'=>__('No snippets found'),
            'not_found_in_trash'=>__('No snippets found in Trash'),
            'parent_item_colon'=>''),
            'public'=>true,
            'publicly_queryable'=>true,
            'show_ui'=>true,
            'query_var'=>true,
            'rewrite'=>false,
            'capability_type'=>'post',
            'supports'=>array('title','thumbnail','comments','revisions','post-formats'),
            'taxonomies'=>array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'slug'=>'snippets',
            'hierarchical'=>false,
            'menu_position'=>4
        ));
    }
    add_action('init', 'post_type_snippets');
```

Comment: You're sure those post types actually have archives? And that `$link` is not `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom mentioned, `$link` is false because your post types don't have archives. You need to add the `has_archive` argument when you register your post types, and set `rewrite` to `true` so the rewrite rule for your archive is generated.

Comment: Oh damn, I didn't realize that was an argument.  I thought it was just a matter of creating it.  Thanks guys.  I must've read thru http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type at least 3 times and totally overlooked that somehow